# How to get element attributes in pQuery

Tags: jquery, html, perl, dom

I'm trying to scrape a website using [pQuery](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/pQuery-0.07/lib/pQuery.pm#HTML) and get the src attribute in all img tags.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
@imgs = pQuery("http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/pQuery-0.07/lib/pQuery.pm")
            ->find("img")
            ->each(sub{
                my $i = shift;
                print $i + 1, ") ", pQuery($_).attr('src'), "\n";
            });
```

The output indicates there are 12 img elements and prints nothing for `.attr('src')`
Is there anywhere with a comprehensive guide of how to use pQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about pQuery, but I suggest to use [Web::Query](https://metacpan.org/pod/Web%3a%3aQuery) instead. Web::Query is alternative module for pQuery.

```
use Web::Query;

wq("http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/pQuery-0.07/lib/pQuery.pm")->find("img")->each(
    sub {
        my $i = shift;
        print $i + 1, ") ", $_->attr('src'), "\n";
    }
);
```

This code works well.

Comment: I am curious about these modules - were are they of benefit, or how have you leveraged them in real life application?

Answer (score 2):

According to the example of each [CPAN~pQuery.pm#each($sub)](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/pQuery-0.07/lib/pQuery.pm#each%28%24sub%29)

I can see pQuery() already contains a dom element finding mechanism if passed an element as its first argument against the domain. Remove the find($sub), and unshift your pQuery arguments with 'img'.

```
my $dom = 'http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/pQuery-0.07/lib/pQuery.pm';
@imgs = pQuery("img", $dom)
        ->each(sub{
            my $i = shift;
            print $i + 1, ') ', pQuery($_).attr('src'), "\n";
        });
```

Is there any reason why you constructed this routine with the extraneous find() rather than use the integrated call method?

Take your time to reread your code against the documentation provided in CPAN and usually there is plenty of information about how the module works.

Comment: thanks for the answer, hopefully it can help others. I ended up ditching pQuery. Also, I copied the code mostly from CPAN to begin with.

Comment: I am glad you found a way to do it :), -- for the language though!